# Different color for navigation bar and status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, ios-statusbar

Is it possible to have different color for navigation bar and status bar ? A solution other than [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238996/set-the-navigation-bar-and-status-bar-with-different-colors) will help. I am looking for some default setting.
What I have tried is, assigning color to navigation bar in storyboard and then for status bar I tried [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7) accepted answer.
But still the status bar has the same color as navigation bar.

Comment: Do you want to set light content to status bar?

Comment: I want navigation bar to be green and status bar to be white :)

Comment: You can put UIView for status bar with height of 20 in UIStoryBoard.

Comment: @PavanJangid : I already mentioned in my question, I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that works very well for me. You can use [setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationBar/setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:) method which sets the background image of the nav bar and does not affect on the status bar of your app. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change status bar background color from ios 7, it is always transparent.

Alternately, you can add a view with the background color you want, and add it to the top, with size as 20px.

Hope this help.